# What to do with .mdump/.hdump files?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++, crash-dumps

I am working on a MySQL user-defined function (UDF) that is basically a wrapper for a Windows system function. My problem is that the UDF works as intended for certain inputs, but causes mysqld to crash for others.

The UDF itself takes a single integer argument that is passed unmodified as a ULONG parameter to the WinAPI function. When this integer is less than a certain number *k*, everything is fine;  but, when the integer is greater than or equal to *k*, the MySQL server process (`mysqld.exe`) consistently crashes.

My 64-bit Windows 7 machine always generates "AppCrash" details that include an MDUMP and HDUMP file. Is there a way to open either of these files in Visual C++ to examine the stack trace at the time of the crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can open crash dumps in Visual Studio.  Windbg is (IMO) the preferred method as it is more powerful, but if all you need is a simple stack trace then Visual Studio would be sufficient.

Comment: Do you know of a good tutorial for Windbg that demonstrates basic usage? I saw one, but it was loading DMP files and I am not sure that the format is the same as HDUMP and/or MDUMP files.